Why poly(isobutylene) is a rubber while poly(propylene) is a plastic
I was asked by my professor why poly(isobutylene) was a rubber while poly(propylene) was a plastic.
The reason probably involves the fact that PIB is more entangled than PP.
My attempt:
i) The trans conformation and gauche conformation in PIB have similar energies due to the two methyl groups. In PP, the trans and gauche conformation have a greater energy difference. Due to this, a greater number of gauche conformations will be present in PIB compared to PP, increasing the chances of entanglement.
ii) For two molecules with the same number of repeating units, PIB will show a greater van der waals force due to a more electrons and more area for polarizability, which would increase the stability of the entanglement.
I'd appreciate some hints on how to answer this. I am a first year student in college, so please answer accordingly.
